# A good strategy for "unclear" questions

Tags: discussion, questions, vote-to-close, unclear

I'm relatively new to SO so please bear with me. I've searched SO Meta for an answer to this question I'm having and haven't found one, so here I go.

I've had the same problem several times:

- I see a badly-worded or bizarre question, unclear on the first read;
- I read it one (or two) more times carefully, or just let it sink in, and then there's a "oh, I get it" moment - the *true meaning* shines through;
- I see from comments that the question is likely to be voted-to-close and that the asker is unable to explain him/herself, either because of a lack of communication skills in English, or because the question is a bit strange or tricky to explain.

To be clear: it's not a "*maybe that's the meaning, I'll have a shot*" cases, it's strong "*oh, I get it*" cases.

Then it's a race:

- Try to answer the question as it stands, but the question is likely to be closed before I can type the answer
- Try to edit it, but the edit has to be reviewed (when not enough rep), so it will probably be visible to late
- Do nothing and just watch the poor guy bashed into the ground because many readers misunderstand his question, and it's closed as "unclear" or "duplicate" in a few minutes.

One the question is closed, time has passed; there are a lot less eyes on it as in the first minutes (I guess), so a re-opening vote is hard to obtain. You see the names of the voters-to-close, but I didn't find an easy way to reach them (comments ? how ?) to notify them of an edit, for instance.

So, what to do? What I'm dreaming of is a kind of "*Wait, I get it!*" button when a question has been VTC. It could involve a penalty if you're wrong, and a time limit, but it's for the case when you're confident enough to answer or edit, and ready to take responsibility if you're wrong.

Maybe it's just a problem when you don't have enough rep, with enough rep do you have other means to act on a question?

### EDIT:

The most voted answer starts with "*don't answer unclear questions*", so clearly there's a need to clarify what unclear means :-)

I don't want to answser questions that are unclear **to me**. For example, I want to answer questions that are strange on first sight but are making sense when you're looking at them the right way. Once you strip away the strangeness, the rest can become trivial. Not english grammar problems, but fuzzier problems that the answer is sorting, but can't be put in an edit without distording the thinking or opinions of the OP.

Here is an exhibit: [Is it right to use the words Deep/Shallow copy of a pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34968040/is-it-right-to-use-the-words-deep-shallow-copy-of-a-pointer?noredirect=1#comment57666873_34968040)

It's voted as a duplicate by voters that probably haven't really bothered to understand the problem of the OP. The referenced answer is about the general concept of deep/shallow, the question is very specifically about the use of the terms in a language where pointers are objects in their own right, and can be also considered (and copied) as "standalone" objects and not as reference to other objects. I don't know if it's a *good* question, but you can't rephrase it without stripping it of its substance. The clarification *is the answer*, in a way.

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen such circumstances before. Can you provide an example of when this has happened?

Comment: My solution to such situations, having a similar rep! is usually to leave a comment saying 'do you mean...' You could always edit the question, and leave a comment telling the OP. I believe they have the unilateral authority to accept a pending change. At that point it is up to them, you've done all you can, though I do often answer such questions (as the question I perceive rather than the question as I read it - which does get downvoted at times!)

Comment: You can also try a [Fastest Gun in the West](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9731/195099) approach. Post a quick answer first, seeing it should make people understand the problem and not close the question, and then make your answer more complete.

Comment: @MichaelB: Yes, the OP has a binding vote on accepting or rejecting edit-suggestions, and is notified of them *by the system*. So adding a comment in addition to the suggestion is not that useful. Also, the problem with answering question without fixing them is that it results in a pretty useless Q&A-pair, which is harder to clean up. And that's even assuming you guessed right!

Comment: @Oriol FGITW is when one is providing *good* answers to *appropriate* questions, and then editing them into *very good* answers later.  It's not about posting bad answers to bad questions.

Comment: @Servy Yes, I was assuming the answer was a good one and the question would become good after the edit.

Comment: @MichaelB thanks, that's helpful advice. Should be an answer IMO.

Comment: @Oriol But the *premise* of the question is that it's unclear, so we *know* it's not a good question.  And given that the question is unclear, it's highly probable that the answer *won't* be a good answer, as the probability that it is based on a misinterpretation of the question is rather high.

Comment: @Servy sorry, my premise is itself not-so-clear (oh the irony). What I should insisted on is that sometimes "unclear" is in the eye of the beholder, not an objective property of the question. The question might still be good, if a bit strange.

Comment: @Ilya If everyone reading the question is unable to understand what it's asking at first, and only a few people are able to come up with a probable guess as to what it might be asking after careful scrutiny, then the question is unclear.  The question could potentially become a good question *once clarified*, but in its current state it isn't.

Comment: @Servy I'm not referring to "probable guess" but to cases where's it's crystal-clear after passing a first barrier (that may or may not exist for a majority of readers). I should probably give examples.

Comment: @Ilya If it was crystal clear then it wouldn't be confusing to most readers, and take so much analysis to figure out what it's asking.  One of the biggest problems with unclear questions, and they reason they get closed, is that lots of people will spend a while looking at it an *think* that they know exactly what it's asking, with 100% certainty, but you'll have several different people who are each entirely confident that the question is asking entirely different things.  This is why we ensure that the questions are clarified before they're answered.

Comment: @Servy sometimes this analysis is part of answering, once you've re-worded the question the rest of the answer is obvious, but if you do that in an edit it doesn't make sense. I'll try to find exemples I'm thinking of, hope they're not deleted.

Comment: @Servy I've edited the question, I hope it helps

Comment: @Ilya My point stands.  Everything that you're describing indicates that the question is unclear.  That you're able to spend considerable effort to try to divine what the question actually meant to ask and that you're confident that you're interpretation is correct doesn't mean that the question is clear.  Those are all indications that the question is unclear.  What it does mean is that you can work with the question author to clarify the question, and that there is potential to transform the question *into* a quality question *even though it's not one yet*.

Comment: *"I want to answer questions that are strange on first sight but are making sense when you're looking at them the right way"* ... sounds like you just described an unclear question that you could possibly edit to make clear. Get to editing!

Comment: Actually, I wouldn't know how to change the question without changing its meaning. The best I could do, once understood, is to answer and clarify at the same time. A "clear" question would not be "good", it would be trivially answerable by a "Yes, right" answer. It's my opinion, anyway.

Comment: @Ilya If you think a question is clear to you but unfortunately not so well formulated that it would be clear to everyone then surely you can try to improve the formulation so that everyone finds that the question is clear. But maybe you only think it's clear and in truth it's not. I have many such cases where I had to abort a clarifying edit because I realized that in the end there is some crucial information missing. But if you think that nothing is missing but only the formulation is a bit overly difficult feel free to improve it and then answer the improved question.

Answer (score 12):

## Don't answer an unclear question.

If it took you a few tries to understand what's going on, chances are it's taken others a few tries to get it too.  That doesn't mean that the question is unanswerable, but it is one of the strongest indicators that the question **needs** to be edited for clarity.

So... **edit it!**

## Putting a question on hold is not its untimely end...

...although it *can* be if the question isn't made clearer, either by the OP or from efforts from the community (rather, those that *can* understand the question).

The view of a question being put on hold isn't one of purgatory; this is meant to give the question time for its errors to be fixed, so that it can be answered clearly.  We don't want rushed answers to a poorly phrased question.

I realize and respect that your edits go into the queue, but that's fine - it gives others time to review the edits and review the question proper, and potentially cast reopen votes on it.

Things get interesting if a question is closed as a duplicate.  If it was a gold badge holder that closed the question, you can @message them and try to demonstrate why the question *isn't* a duplicate.  However, the onus is more on the OP than the community at large to prove that their `NullPointerException` question *isn't* just a case in which they forgot to initialize a field.

Comment: See edited question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975138/representing-a-number-as-a-weighted-average-of-some-fixed-numbers?noredirect=1#comment57681270_34975138. Probably forerever "on hold as unclear" in spite of editing.

Comment: @Ilya:  There are several new problems with that post - now, it appears to be asking for reference to a library which is indeed off-topic here.

Comment: That's the reason ? Should it not be another vote ?

Comment: @Ilya:  Unless the question can be edited to feel less like a library request, you'd be hard pressed to have that question remain open...

Comment: I don't think it's right to change the reason why the question is closed without any notifications. The question, as it is now, is clear, so it's confusing if its status is "closed because unclear, please clarify". The cause should be updated in such a case. At least, someone judging that there's another problem should comment.

Comment: @Ilya:  What I'm saying is, if it were to be reopened, it'd be closed for another reason.  The general advice above still stands in that you shouldn't answer an unclear question, but the question you highlight has more problems that just clarity.

Comment: "if it were to be reopened, it'd be closed for another reason." That would be fine if that happens. What I'm saying is that this feedback is missing.

Comment: BTW, if that question was redacted to just ask for an algorithm instead of "library or algorithm", would it be on-topic ? Like that one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/127704/algorithm-to-return-all-combinations-of-k-elements-from-n

Answer (score 4):

Well, you don't really want to notify the users who voted to close, they might have left for the day/week/month/forever.
And anyway, unless they *really* did something wrong, or they had a binding vote (and thus can undo it as efficiently), you shouldn't bother them anyway.
Any five 3K users you convince by fixing the question can reopen.

The first edit to a closed question within 9 days of closing or so puts the question into the reopen queue.
As does a reopen-vote (3K needed), and some other conditions.
As that queue is just about always empty, the community's verdict on the improved question will be in quite fast, be it to leave it closed or to reopen.

Comment: The only open issue seems to be: first edit the question then answer or first answer and then edit or wait if it gets closed and then edit. Is there any argument why one should prefer one way over the other?

Comment: Well, if you edit first, it's less likely to get closed at all. If you answer first, you won't risk having to wait for reopening, but will get a worse reception, especially if you don't fix it expeditiously. But waiting until it is closed is at best a waste, you can clarify further later if needed...